# Netscaler ADC setup scheduled Clearing Persistence

Tags: netscaler

Is there a way of setting up some type of CRON job on the Netscaler VPX running firmware 11.0 to automatically clear Persistence Session Records on a daily basis?

https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/netscaler/12/load-balancing/load-balancing-persistence/clearing-persistence.html

Comment: I will explore adding clear lb persistentSessions [<vServer> in
/etc/crontab 

Next challenge is figuring out exact syntax and how to configure not overwriting on reboots. According to a blog anything in /etc is just in RAM.

https://blog.norz.at/scheduling-commands-on-citrix-netscaler-from-crontab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the /nsconfig folder you have a rc.netscaler file. 
Make a entry in the rc.netscaler where you add the cron job.

When you reboot the rc.netscaler will be executed.

You can also put files in the /var directory (survives reboot) and use an entry in /nsconfig/rc.netscaler to copy to /etc/....

Answer (score 0):

setup a cron job on the netscaler freebsd. use the following structure for your command:

```
nscli -U xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:nsroot:nsroot "clear lb persistentSessions"
```

edit to add the following note: keep in mind you will most likely impact anyone connected at the time when running this command (depends on your application)